# Plotting histograms separately by a list of data in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a nested list, whose data I need to plot on different histograms.

```
    ...
    ...
    numbers = [[float(line[1]) for line in chr ] for chr in result]
    plt.hist(numbers)
    plt.show()
```

Doing so, the output is one only figure, with the bars of the different histograms in each bin (for instance the first bin contains the first bar of every histogram) Instead what I want is to have separate histograms.
I tried to do a for cycle:

```
    for w in numbers:
       plt.hist(w)
       plt.show()
```

but doing so I obtaine only a histogram per time, and I am allowed to see the next one, only when i close the previous one.
What shall I do?

Answer (score 3):

Use [subplots](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#working-with-multiple-figures-and-axes). Choose `n_rows` and `n_columns` such that you can make `len(numbers)` subplots. `i` starts at 1, not 0.

```
i = 1
for w in numbers:
    plt.subplot(n_rows, n_columns, i)
    i += 1
    plt.hist(w)
plt.show()
```

By taking `plt.show()` out of the for loop the figure is drawn on the screen only once and there is no need to close earlier incomplete versions.

Comment: Can you accept the answer? It is the best way to let other people know that the question is answered. (and I get the credits :) )